a status of 404 () when deploying to Vercel
I keep running into the 404(sometimes 405 on Vercel.
My project is running perfectly fine locally.
The live preview is live
Front end + back end code here repo
The error message is:
enter image description here
I tried adding a vercel.json that looked like this:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "build"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "api/main.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/main.py"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

But this led to a 404 for the entire web app

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
